# Uncaught Error: invalid address when transferring token

Tags: web3js, tokens, metamask, javascript

When I try to transfer the token from 1 address to another, the error in the title pops up.
Here is my relevant JS code:
`$("#targetAddr").val()` is the address of the target address (in metamask) and  `$("#amt").val()` is the value of the tokens to transfer to.

```
tokenContract.transfer($("#targetAddr").val().toString(),$("#amt").val())
```

I am using a smart contract that is very similar to OpenZepplin's ERC20. Its transfer is similar to ERC20's transfer function. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code of my token contract setup in javascript:

```
var tokenContractAddress = token_contract_address;
//coinABI is the ABI from my smart contract.
var tokenContract = web3.eth.contract(coinABI).at(tokenContractAddress);
```

The address that is in the input is one of the addresses in my metamask account (essentially a valid address)

Comment: Can you print the address you are sending? if you look it up on etherscan does it match the required case for the checkSum to be correct?

Comment: i searched it on etherscan and etherscan said it appeared in a ropsten test network (yes im using ropsten)